# What could be the Model Layer when consuming Web-Services and no Database in Django?

Tags: django, web-services, mvc

I'm using Django as an application framework and it only needs to consume web services (no need to have traditional Django Models and the related ORM).

In this case, since Django is a variant on the MVC architecture (MVT, to be precise) should I wrap the web service calls into a 'model' that my App uses or should I just call those web services directly from the Django View and remove the model layer?

Comment: Why are you using Django when all you want is call other webservices?

Comment: Hi @SimeonVisser thank you for your Answer :) I'm using it because I want to start working on Python, and I want to enjoy the facilities he offers like : Generating a backoffice etc..

Comment: yes, but what will you use it for? You won't be using the database, the models, the ORM and it doesn't look like you're looking for views/templates either. Where are you going to store the data to show it to the business?

Comment: @SimeonVisser, I will use the Templates/Views I only have an issue in the usefulness of the model and it's content :)

Answer (score 1):

you just run the syncdb and there are some extra tables which you never use from the views
also the views (at least on older djangos) has nothing to do with the models, just you can use models or not
so you just make an empty models.py for your new app
and btw it is called MTV and not MVC

Answer (score 0):

I question the design choice of using a now-pretty-heavyweight web-framework and neglecting to use major parts of it. Look into using something like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) instead.